# finding lines that Don't match a given pattern

Tags: regex, grep

I have a large file and I want to print the lines that do not match a particular undesired pattern. The following does the exact opposite of what I want, namely it retains all the undesirable lines.

```
grep -e '\[0.0, 0.0\]' locscore.txt
```

How can I get the lines that DON'T have the above pattern?
I tried

```
grep -e '^*(?!\[0.0, 0.0\])*$' locscore.txt
```

but it produces nothing.

Comment: This question is easily answered by reading the man page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use grep, there is an option `-v`, it does what you need.

from man page:

```
  -v, --invert-match
              Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)
```