# grep and don't show lines that containa a certain string

Tags: grep

I have the following command and output

```
$ find . -iname '*custom_layout_width*'
find: ‘./etc/apps/learned/local’: Permission denied
./etc/apps/search/appserver/static/custom_layout_width.js
find: ‘./etc/apps/search/local’: Permission denied
./etc/apps/simple_xml_examples/appserver/static/custom_layout_width.js
find: ‘./etc/apps/simple_xml_examples/local’: Permission denied
find: ‘./etc/apps/splunk_management_console/lookups’: Permission denied
```

I would like not to show lines that DO NOT contain the string `Permission`.

How can I do this? 
I was thinking of using a grep, bu i am obviously not that good.

`$ find . -iname '*custom_layout_width*' | grep '!Permission'`

**EDIT1** found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471338/finding-lines-that-dont-match-a-given-pattern) but using -v does not seem to work for me

Comment: Redirect stderr to /dev/null: `find . -iname '*custom_layout_width*' 2>/dev/null`

Comment: tks that does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect the error to `/dev/null`.

```
find . -iname '*custom_layout_width*' 2>/dev/null
```

Following will not work ,

```
find . -iname '*custom_layout_width*' | grep '!Permission'
```

Because, pipe is get the input from stdout and pass it as input to the next command. But here `Permission Denied` will come in stderr. So  piping will not work.

For that you can do like this,

```
find / -iname "hi" 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission"
```

`2>&1` It is  merging the `stderr` to `stdout`. Now the `stderr` content will be placed in the `stdout`.

Comment: why the `/` as opposed to the `.`

Comment: `/` is represents the root directory. `.` is represents the current working directory. Based on this only searching will be done.